# Best practice : use enum or not to store dropdown values

Tags: c#, enums, html-select

I'm developping an application and I often ask myself the same question.

For example, I have many types of user and in a form used to create a user, there is a dropdown to specify which type of user.

The best way to populate this dropdown is to store values in a database's table ? If I do this, when I develop I want to test type of user and I have only an int. But I thing it's a better practice to test with enum. So I create enum but I feel it's a bad practice because I have to keep database and enum synchronized.

Another question is about localization. If I put values in database, I can't use resource file.

Could you tell me good pratices about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your situation - the database would be the best practice here especially if its dynamic data. enum is for those values which are *rarely* to change, maybe once in a while but not on a frequent basis. you may have new entries entered in the database regularly especially for things like cascading drop down lists.

database certainly is the way to go in your situation. Enums are there for those times where they are just a set standard and rarely to change, for example:

Mr.
Miss.
Mrs.
Ms.
Dr.

you would have these in enums as they will never really change. on the other hands if store departments are to be changed or renamed, database would be the place to store such entries.

Comment: I agree with your example, and dynamic data don't ask me problem. I ask myself for example like "Mr. Mss. Mrs. ...".  So in this case, do you develop a control to render a label for each enum value ? Or do you hard coded in the page ?

Comment: that depends on you. I usually use an custom attribute on the enums so then I use reflection to give me a list of strings which contain the enum description and then render it on the page. you could make a user control with a drop down list, and you give it a List of keyvaluepair, where a key would be an int and a value would be the description to display. the int would be like an "ID" of some kind.

Comment: I use also the description attribute, but I have to localize this strings. Moreover, I think it's a bad practice to store text in code. I think about use a resourceKey in description attribute, What do you think about this ?

Comment: yes, sorry - this is what I meant. using a resource dictionary of some kind.

Comment: it's my conclusion too, but I was not sure of this practice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I strongly disagree with using enums for this kind of functionality, for basically two reasons:

- Enumeration values have no behaviour, so compromise good OOP. A good class has data + behaviour, so enumeration members are not sufficiently specialised to represent the concept they are named for. The logic concerning this domain object lives somewhere else other than the entity that bears its name, which I dislike.
- Enumerations are meant to convey ordinality, so `DaysOfWeek` is a good usage (except that which day of the week is 'first' varies depending on culture, but that' nitpicking) because the enumeration denotes the **order** of its members. In your case, does it make sense to say that a particular value is the 'first' user type, the second value is second, and so on? Probably not.

Comment: For example, I develop a businnes layer for invoices. I have an invoice type on my Invoice object. Your response means that's not good to use enum to type invoice because it doesn't influe on behaviour of the invoice ? However, this type allows me to modify the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be - do you actually use the user type anywhere in the database?
If the answer is no, everything is easier, since you can simply use an enum and be done with it.

Otherwise, you probably should have a user type table as well, to get to use foreign keys properly.

Personally, I use manual ID for these - autogenerated keys can make a mess of your attempts to synchronize code and database. Ideally, if your ORM allows it, you could have the code-database synchronization automatic - either through code generation, or through automatic database data update. If you can't, though, manually coding the enums (or some kind of pseudo enum) should still be a lot nicer in the code.

As for localization, your options are completely the same. Just use a resource key like "UserType-XXX", where XXX is the database ID of the type. If you want, you can also store the localized values in the database. Just do whatever feels the best for your application.

Comment: The user type is just an example, I don't use reference in other tables. I don't user orm.

Comment: Well, if that's so, I'd just go with the enum. If it's not used anywhere in the DB logic, creating it in the database would just make everything more complicated, and give you nothing for it.